# Debug - How to Access virtual host from Virtual Box machine?

Tags: virtualbox, localhost, mamp

If I configure my virtual box with NAT I can access my localhost MAMP page with: 10.0.2.2

If I configure windows hosts file with: 10.0.2.2 mysite.dev

I could then access that same information by typing on the browser mysite.dev is this correct ?

So, if we do: mysite.dev we will see MAMP localhost page.

The thing is: I wish NOT to see the MAMP localhost page. Instead, I wish to see my under development site page.

On the host OS, I go to the browser and I do: http://mysite.dev (and I see my dev site files); (files located on: /Users/myuser/Sites/mysiteDev/)

If I do: http://localhost (I see the MAMP page) (files located on: /Applications/MAMP/htdocs)

Question: How can I configure the Virtual Host Machine (Windows Vista SP2) so that, when we issue on the browser:

http://mysite.dev we can see my development pages AND NOT the MAMP page ?